# При верстке макета блоки смешались

Tags: html, css

Верстаю лендинг и один блок упрямо лезет на предыдущий, вместо того, чтобы идти за ним.

```css
.fifth-part {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50.833em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.backgr {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.big-img {
  width: 25.750em;
  height: 35.500em;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 30em;
  padding-top: 2.7em;
  z-index: 3;
}
.small-img {
  width: 20.667em;
  height: 35.833em;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 45em;
  padding-top: 9em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
}
/*слайдер*/

.sixth-part {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24.167em;
  // background: #f8f8f8;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: pink;
}
.quote-img_s {
  width: 5.000em;
  height: 5.417em;
}
```

```html
<div class="fifth-part">
  <div class="fifth-part_s">
    <img class="backgr" src="images/45.jpg" alt="#">
    <span class="one">We work with</span>
    <span class="two">AMAZING SERVICES</span>
    <span class="no-text_no">_____</span>
    <img class="big-img" src="images/p.png" alt="#">
    <img class="small-img" src="images/White.png" alt="#">
  </div>
</div>

<!--слайдер -->
<div class="sixth-part">
  <div class="sixth-part_s">
    <div class="quote-img">
      <img class="quote-img_s" src="images/SPEECH.png" alt="#">
    </div>
    <div class="quote-text">
      <span class="quote-text_quote">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi placeat, laborum ratione laboriosam reprehenderit modi magni. Quaerat doloribus a aliquam necessitatibus explicabo, esse aliquid laudantium porro. Voluptatum alias nihil iusto."</span>
      <span class="quote-text_autor">John Doe</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Для наглядности блок, который должен быть внизу, сделала с розовым фоном

Comment: потому, что оба блока в `position: absolute;`

Comment: исправила, работает, спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> один блок упрямо лезет на предыдущий, вместо того, чтобы идти за ним

потому, что оба блока `fifth-part` и `sixth-part` имеют свойство `position: absolute;`